# removing duplicates using awk in unix

Tags: unix, ubuntu, awk

My file is in the format

```
>id1
sequence1
>id2
sequence2
>id1
sequence3
```

the output i want is:

```
>id1
sequence1
>id2
sequence2
```

i.e. I need to remove sequences and id both in pairs if id is repeat.

I tried the following code, but it doesnt work.

```
awk '{
if(NR%2 == 1)
{
    fastaheader = $0; x[fasta_header] = x[fasta_header] + 1; 
}
else 
{
    seq = $0; {if(x[fasta_header] <= 1) {print fasta_header;print seq;}}
}
}' filename.txt
```

Comment: If you get two entries for ID = 'id1', will the sequence information always be the same in both entries? Or are you really looking at `id1` with `sequence1A` and `id1` with `sequence1B`, and you only want the `sequence1A` entry to be shown. Or is it the combination of `id1` plus the sequence data that must be duplicated in its entirety (so you'd want both `id1` with `sequence1A` and `id1` with `sequence1B` to appear in the output)? Your question says "Remove ID and sequence if the ID is repeated"; your comments say "Remove ID and sequence if the combination of ID and sequence are repeated".

Comment: If you need to compare both the ID and the sequence information, then the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21275633/15168) by [Jotne](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2341847/jotne) is the way to go.  However, you also need to fix your question so it asks for that, not just for detecting repeated ID values as it currently does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though the ID lines start with `>`. Given the order of the output, you want the first sequence associated with a given ID, not the last.  This means you need something like:

```
awk '/^>/ { if (id[$1]++ == 0) printing = 1; else printing = 0 }
          { if (printing) print }'
```

The first line decides whether the current ID is unique and sets `printing` to 1 if it is, and 0 otherwise.  The second line notes whether printing is required, and prints appropriately. Note that if there's more than one line of data in the sequence, it is quite happy to print all those lines. It does not rely on there being just one line in the sequence data.

Comment: You does not take in care that sequence numbers needs to be tested too, see my example `file2`

Comment: what does '/^>/  do??

Comment: It looks for lines that start with a `>` sign.

Comment: @see my post for `file2`, but it would be interesting to see what priyanka responds to your question.

Comment: @Jotne: I've stated in my second comment to the question that your answer is good for one interpretation of what's wanted (and left unsaid that mine is good for a different interpretation of what's wanted).  I confess to being puzzled about what actually is wanted; the comments don't match the question precisely, and seemed to favour your interpretation of what's wanted.  Ambiguity — what would we do without it?

Comment: @OP has now change the request, so yours are correct answer to what he want.

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
awk '{a[$0]++} END {for (i in a) print RS i}' RS=">" file | awk '!/^>?$/'
>id1
sequence1
>id2
sequence2
```

---

Using the `RS=">"` changes the record to include both `id` and `sequence.`

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' RS=">"
id1 sequence1
id2 sequence2
id1 sequence1
```

Then the array removes all duplicate

The last `awk '!/^>?$/'` just removes some blank spaces and an extra `>`

---

```
cat file2
>id1
sequence1
>id2
sequence2
>id1
sequence3
```

This file should be intact, since the number in sequence are all difference.

```
awk '{a[$0]++} END {for (i in a) print RS i}' RS=">" file2 | awk '!/^>?$/'
>id1
sequence1
>id2
sequence2
>id1
sequence3
```

Comment: Thanks, but can u please explain this? I need to generalise it to case where id,sequence, num are triplets and num may be different, even when id and sequence is same.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your ids and sequences are always exactly one line:

```
awk 'NR%2 && !a[$0]++ { print; getline l ; print l }' input
```

Comment: If I am correct you only test `ID` and ignores the sequence number.  It needed to be tested too.  Se my post example with `file2`

Comment: Jotne, you are correct. I am ignoring the sequence number, since the question states "remove sequences and id both in pairs if id is repeat."

Comment: OP has changed his post to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer `awk`, you don't need pipe, and it prints lines in the sequence they appear in original file.

If you don't mind the line sequence, you can use `sort`

```
xargs -n2 < file  | sort -uk1,1 | xargs -n1
```